# Undefined class Socialite in Spark Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite, laravel-spark

I'm new to Laravel and Spark trying to figure out how/where I should add my new Controllers and add Socialite.

In my providers I added

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

In my aliases I added

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Here's what my app/HTTP/Controllers/Auth/LoginController class looks like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::with('github')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

I get undefined class Socialite when I add `use Socialite;`

I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear` but nothing is working. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Socialite 3.0

Thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to assume you did the `composer require laravel/socialite` step?

Comment: and does doing `use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite` instead make a difference?

Comment: Yes I re-installed it, tried using use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite instead and now I get the following error: method "with" not found in Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

Comment: OK, so that's progress - it can find the class. The new error is because it should be `Socialite::driver('github')`, not `Socialite::with('github')`.

Comment: I also get method "driver" not found in `Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;` the only method available in the facade is getFacadeAccessor but I should be able to use other functions right?

Comment: Since you've got the package installed now, does `use Socialite` work again?

Comment: No it still doesn't :/

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

This will clear the current compiled files, update the classes it needs and then write them back out so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: Tried it and it's still not working :/ any alias I try to use doesn't recognize it. Tried restarting Phpstorm IDE, nothing seems to work